# Deny access to "bat" files in Apache

Tags: windows, apache-2.4, permissions, .htaccess, xampp

I want to deny direct access to some sensitive files in my root application (e.g: log,sh, ini ...etc).
and for this reasons I have used the following directive in my main .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch  "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log|sh|inc|bak|md|txt|lock|phar|bat)$|action.bat|composer.json|VERSION.*">
  Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

the wierd thing is that it work perfectly fo all files listed in the FileMatch except files with (.bat) extention, which I did not figure yet whythey still downloadable using direct URL access.
**Configuration:**

- OS: Windows 10
- Stack: XAMPP

**XAMPP components version:**

- Apache 2.4.39
- MariaDB 10.1.38
- PHP 7.3.4 (VC15 X86 64bit thread safe) + PEAR
- phpMyAdmin 4.8.5
- OpenSSL 1.1.0g
- XAMPP Control Panel Version 3.2.3.

---

Update:

> actually I
>   discover that the Pattern Matching works with all ".bat" files except
>   the ones with name "action" ! if I change the name to anything
>   else (lets say "action1" ) it works just fine.

Comment: Presumably the reason for adding `action.bat` specifically was because this file was not blocked with the existing regex that simply blocked all `.bat` files? (Note: by adding `action.bat` to the regex, as you have done, you are blocking `.action.bat` (dot prefix) - so this isn't actually helping.)

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you have should work. You should be able to also delete `action.bat|` and it should function the same. If your file does not end with `.bat`, that might be causing issues.

A simplified explanation of what it does:

```
\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log|sh|inc|bak|md|txt|lock|phar|bat)$
|||                                                          |
||^Any string within brackets (separated with | as "or")     |
|^Any character or . when escaped     End of filename marker ^
^Escape character
```

Try restarting your server, ensure you're working in the correct directory and make sure there isn't anything else working against the rules you're establishing in this .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. actually the extra full name "action.bat" is just to insurance purpose.
for the file it ended with ".bat" extention. indeed I discover that the Pattern Matching works with all ".bat" files except with the ones with name "action" ! if I change the name to anything else (lets say "action1" ) it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can add following to your vhost file

## To deny specific files access

```
<Files *.bat>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

You can add your extension type according to your requirements.

Comment: Actually I discover that the Pattern Matching works with all ".bat" files except with the ones with name "action" ! if I change the name to anything else (let's say "action1" ) it works just fine.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried your Directive. and as i have already mentioned, the files with "action.bat" name still accessible.

Comment: Access control with `Order` and `Deny` is deprecated in Apache 2.4, see [https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access).